# scanf() problems in C

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

I am solving the problem that compares the array that is filled with numbers which are randomly generated by the computer and array that human asked to input numbers. I did pretty well on the first one but have a problem with stacking numbers in the human array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// numbers that are randomly generated by the computer
int Array_comp (int (*comp)) 
{
    int j,i;
    for (j = 0; j < 3; )
    {
        i = rand();
        if (i < 10)
        {
            comp[j]=i;
            j++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand((int)time(NULL));
    int arr_comp[3]={};
    int arr_hum[3]={};


    Array_comp (arr_comp);

    // enter three numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("number %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d ",&arr_hum[i]);
    }

    // print input numbers 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",arr_hum[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

these are my code for this problem. For me, it seems like there is no problem with stacking numbers in the human array.

However, the result is different from my thought.
[image]

this is the result of the code. My initial intention is to stacking numbers something like

```
number 1:1

number 2:2

number 3:3
```

and printed results different from this. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: You read three number. You input four number. Then you print three numbers. Why should the fourth number be read and printed?

Comment: `int arr_comp[3]={};` is non-standard, use `int arr_comp[3]={0};`

Comment: Also please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part. If you have code that is irrelevant to the problem you ask about, we really don't need to see it.

Comment: Do not define functions beginning with uppercase.

Comment: `i = rand() % 10;` would be much simpler than looping hoping to get a random less that 10... (where in your case you likely never actually store anything in `comp[]`)

Comment: Better, your entire `Array_comp()` function can reduce to `void Array_comp (int *comp) { int j; for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) comp[j] = rand() % 10; }`

Comment: thank you so much for the help. I am noob in programming so, sorry for the improper format of posting and also thanks for other corrections I learned a lot from that.

Answer (score 2):

The *problem* you have is that trailing extra space in the `scanf()` format specifier. It needs to match *additional* whitespace(s) in order to get the scanning done.

```
  scanf("%d ",&arr_hum[i]);
```

change to

```
  scanf("%d",&arr_hum[i]);
```